# Serialization return type

Tags: java, serialization, return

```
public Manager restoreManager(String fileName) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    // Read from disk using FileInputStream
    FileInputStream f_in = new FileInputStream(fileName);

    // Read object using ObjectInputStream
    ObjectInputStream obj_in = new ObjectInputStream(f_in);

    // Read an object
    Object obj = obj_in.readObject();

    return ????? ;
}
```

I'm "returning a Manager Object based on the serialization data found in the file", but I don't know what exactly I should be returning from the code, I can't return just an object, because the return type is Manager.
This is my first time working with serialization, so I'm unsure of what to do here.

I've tried

```
return Manager(obj);
return obj;
```

***Just tried

```
return (Manager) obj;
```

and that is working!!

Comment: Doesn't `return (Manager)obj;` work?

Comment: I tried that and it gave me an error saying that
The method Manager(Object) is undefined for the type SystemManager

Comment: cast obj to Manager and return it!

Comment: You are making some syntax error. Post what have you tried.

Comment: It's `return (Manager)obj;` not `return Manager(obj);`!

Comment: Yup!  Eclipse told me that I was doing it wrong, my mistake!  But yes
return (Manager)obj; worked, thank you so much!

Comment: @CCC, If this question is resolved, you should post the answer and mark it as accepted (when possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's

```
return (Manager)obj;
```

not

```
return Manager(obj);
```

! – johnchen902 Apr 20 at 5:05